# How do I list all guilds my bot is in with their respective ids

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

been trying to figure this out for 15 minutes now and to no prevail

code:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
    client.user.setActivity('you type commands uwu', { type: 'WATCHING' });
    console.log(`${client.user.username} is fully active.`);
    console.log(`${client.guilds}`)
})
```

Right now I'm just trying to get the id's but I need both and this is really annoying to figure out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mup guild collection.

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
    client.user.setActivity('you type commands uwu', { type: 'WATCHING' });
    console.log(`${client.user.username} is fully active.`);
    let guilds = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id) // for discord v11 //let guilds = client.guilds.map(guild => guild.id)
    console.log(guilds)
})
```